# Armature copy rotation apply when the operation is canceled

Tags: armature

I can work around this problem, but I wish to know why...

I press  <kbd>R</kbd> or  <kbd>G</kbd> to rotate or move the bone (neck) or related bones, then cancel the operation (<kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd>), but there is still a change in the rotation of the bone (neck).

If I disable the *Copy Rotation* of this bone, it works normally.
I tried to delete all keyframes but that change nothing.

[image]

https://pasteall.org/media/8/1/81f6c714060325ef89eacfd4a5d1f6ef.blend

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem but it looks like there's a cicular dependency as your head_main is child of neck_hinge, neck copy the rotation of head_main, and neck_hinge copy the rotation of neck?

Comment: neck_hinge copy the rotation of the neck -- or not, depending of the Influency factor. I see now that the problem is resolved if I clear the parent of the head_main, so now it's just that the rig dosen't do what it should anymore

Comment: maybe describe what you want exactly so that we find the right armature to do that?

Comment: 'head_main' shloud be rotating 'head' with 100% influence, and 'neck' with 50%. So whien I rotate 'main_head' the neck is not 100% affected, and when I rotate  'chest_control', I can decide wether or not 'neck' and 'head' follow the movement by changing de Influence factor of the 'neck_hinge' modifier.  It works fine, except for that strange behavior of moving when I cancel the rotation with RMB

Comment: It's getting too complicated for me  ^^  I hope someone will answer